# Run python script function in remote machine

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have script in remote device and I want to run specific function in python script in  remote device

remote device has below script:

```
#connect.py

class ConnectDevice:
    def __init__(self, ip):
        connect.Device(ip)
    def get_devicestate(self):
        state = show.Device_State  
        return state
```

## configured password less connection from source machine to remote machine

function get_devicestate return up or down.

How to get get_devicestate output from source machine. source machine has below script:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import getpass
import errno
import json
import subprocess
import threading
from subprocess import call
from subprocess import check_output
call(["ssh", "1.1.1.1", "\"python Connect.py\""])#This is just example how to run script from source to remote. Need help how to run function get_devicestate and get value.
```

Comment: Have a look at the ``-c`` switch of ``python``. It lets you feed in a script via the command line.

Comment: Hi MisterMiyagi, I did not get your statement, Can you explain

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance , it seems that connect.py has got more code than you have pasted in your question. Anyways, assuming connect.py does not require any input parameters to run, simply use subprocess's check_output method to get the stdout message and store it in a variable for further use.

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output(["ssh", "1.1.1.1", "\"python Connect.py\""])
```

Comment: How to pass argument IP to script connect.py?

Comment: if you want to pass the variable IP on the command line , then you will have to write the script in such a away that it accepts command line arguments. This can easily be done using argparse library for python. Documentation can be found at https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html